# LaravelRalationship can't access

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

First of all sorry for my bad english..
I have a problem with model relationships, I can't access my data from controller and from view, could you help?

I have two table category and categorydescription

**categories table is going like this**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image', 255)->nullable();
            $table->integer('parent_id')->defaut(0);
            $table->tinyInteger('top');
            $table->integer('column');
            $table->integer('sort_order')->defaut(0);
            $table->tinyInteger('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

** categories_description table as you see **

```
Schema::create('categories_description', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            // $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('languages');
            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('meta_title', 255);
            $table->string('meta_description', 255);
            $table->string('meta_keyword', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and I create two model for them Category model and CategoryDescription model **Thas are my model **

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function selectQuery($sql_stmt) {
        return DB::select($sql_stmt);
    }

    public function sqlStatement($sql_stmt) {
        DB::statement($sql_stmt);
    }

    public function categorydescription() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\CategoryDescription', 'categories_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and second model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoryDescription extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories_description';

    public function selectQuery($sql_stmt) {
        return DB::select($sql_stmt);
    }

    public function sqlStatement($sql_stmt) {
        DB::statement($sql_stmt);
    }
}
```

and my home controller code for fetching data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Category;
use App\Model\CategoryDescription;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->categories = Category::with('categorydescription')->get(); // where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->

    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {

        $res = $this->categories;
        foreach($res as $desc) {
            echo $desc->id;
            echo "<br>";
            foreach ($desc->categorydescription() as $key) {
                echo "<hr>";
                echo $key->id;
                echo "<hr>";
            }
        }

        // die();
        // return view('home', [
        //     'title'         => 'Home',
        //     'categories'    => $this->categories,
        // ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what you're trying to achieve here. The way you described relation in model, a category will have multiple descriptions. Is that what you want to build?

Comment: What is the problem?  What have you tried, and what happened?

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the relationship method as property `$desc->categorydescription()` instead of this, you have to use it as follows  `$desc->categorydescription`

Try with the following

```
public function index() {

        $res = $this->categories;
        foreach($res as $desc) {
            echo $desc->id;
            echo "<br>";
            foreach ($desc->categorydescription as $key) {
                echo "<hr>";
                echo $key->id;
                echo "<hr>";
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: You can make this answer if really works for you, it will help others too